# Serve static files in Express from AWS S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, reverse-proxy, static-files

I have a requirement in which static files(CSS,JS files) are copied to a private AWS S3 location and I need to serve those static files in my Express application from that AWS S3 location.

I tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware, for this use-case.

Sample code below:

```
import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware';

const app = express();

app.use(
  '/static',
  createProxyMiddleware({
    target: s3 location url,
    changeOrigin: true,
  })
);

app.listen(3000);
```

Somehow its failing, Is there a better way to do it, or I am missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

To directly proxy it from your node.js app, you'll have to make the bucket in publicly accessible mode if it is in private mode

Comment: Thanks Ankit, Bucket is already publicly available, actually if I rephrase my question, Is it possible to serve static files in express from a different location.(Because we can serve the static files from the current executing directory https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: You can try using this package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-proxy